# Warning: Uglification failed. Unexpected token: eof (undefined)

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I use uglify with grunt, and for some reason it throws a warning on my app file:

> Warning: Uglification failed. Unexpected token: eof (undefined).  Line
>   15472 in dist/app.annotated.js  Use --force to continue.

This is the file with lines:

```
15469   $scope.selectLocation = function () {
15470       $("#locationIframe").html('');
15471       if (($scope.LeadObj.address1 == "" || $scope.LeadObj.address1 == null) && $scope.LeadObj.ip != null) {
15472           $scope.showLocation = 'loading';
15473           $.ajax({
15474               type: 'GET',
```

Besides the fact that this code is stupid, why do I get this warning? it all checks out..

Comment: `EOF` means that the file ends when it's still expecting to see more code. Is there a line 15475?

Comment: @Pointy There are thousands of more rows. Using the app.annotated.js works for me (no errors in console), but it for some reason fails to uglify

Comment: This kind of thing usually suggests there's an invisible character in your code. There doesn't seem to be in the code in the question, but if it wasn't pure copy-and paste (or even in some cases if it were), it could have been dropped.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OK, I copied the code I wrote here, back to my source file, and still there is the same problem, meaning an invisible charecter could not have droped

Comment: Maybe you should just do wc -l dist/app.annotated.js. If the line count goes beyond 15472, you probably want to check how many bytes are listed in for the file when doing `ls -l` vs actual bytes in file.

Comment: @SureshKoya ws-l returns 15022. which is less then 15472. What does it mean?

Comment: @Amit: Perhaps your line endings are inconsistent, sometimes `\r\n`, other times just `\n`? But it tells you that the error from uglify isn't on the line you think it is, it's at the end of the file.

Comment: But 15472 is not the end of the file. 15895 is. and ws -l returns 15022 which I dont get.. and I did remove all line breaks, and beautified the file again, no luck

Comment: Get all the line endings to a uniform pattern using dos2unix command and rerun the command.

Comment: Also since you are using Angular, did you check your [angular instructions](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) for minification?

Comment: Did that work after doing dos2unix?

Comment: @SureshKoya Yes! Thank you. I used "grunt-lineending" to convert the file in place, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the problem was with how the lines ended. Not all of them ended in the UNIX style of `\n`.

The solution was to use `grunt-lineending` to convert the file to use correct line endings before uglifying.

```
lineending: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            overwrite: true,
            eol: 'lf'
        },
        files: {
            '': ['dist/**/*.js']
        }
    }
},
```